# Chaiscript string problem between Visual Studio and Xcode

Tags: c++, chaiscript

I've hit a very weird bug or most probably I'm missing something. My script runs perfectly when compiled with VS 2015 but fails when I switch to Mac and use Xcode 9.

The problem is, on Mac, chaiscript removes the beginning of returned strings. I don't know why? Here's the problem:
On C++ side I have a class like this that connects to an API and stores API reply in JSONString:

```
class MyClass
{
  public string JSONString;
  public void Get(URL);
}
```

This class is instantiated from chaiscript and contains JSON data. Here's the code:

```
def GetAPIData()
{
  var myurl = "Https://api.domain.com";
  auto &request = MyClass();
  request.Get(myurl);
  return request.JSONString;
}

var response = GetAPIData();
```

When I log the string from GetAPIData, on Windows it's something like this:

```
[{"id": 91, "name": "aaa", "status": "Active"}, {"id": 2, "name": "bbb", "status": "Active"}]
```

On Mac:

```
: "aaa", "status": "Active"}, {"id": 2, "name": "bbb", "status": "Active"}]
```

Why this could be happening?

Comment: So you have a class, `MyClass`, that behaves differently on Windows and Mac. Any chance you could show us the code for `MyClass`? That would seem to be where the trouble is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this a bug. I was able to work around the issue by wrapping request.JSONString with to_string().

```
def GetAPIData()
{
  var myurl = "Https://api.domain.com";
  auto &request = MyClass();
  request.Get(myurl);
  return to_string(request.JSONString);
}
```